# Tableau Embedding API v3 - Promise not resolving for getMarksAsync() function

Tags: javascript, promise, tableau-api, es6-promise, tableau-desktop

We are currently exploring the possibility of grabbing selected values when users click on marks using Tableau Embedding API V3.

However, Whenever I click on the event, the event is triggered but, the promise is showing as pending.

Can you please check the following and let me know if there is any mistake from my side in resolving the promise.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Tableau 8 Javascrip API</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getSelectedMarks(marksEvent) {
                alert('Triggered');
                console.log(marksEvent.detail.getMarksAsync().then(reportSelectedMarks));
                // const marksSelected = await marksEvent.detail.getMarksAsync();
                // const numMarks = marksSelected.data[0].data.length;
                // alert(`${numMarks} marks Selected`);
            }
            
            function reportSelectedMarks(marks) {
                console.log(marks);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <tableau-viz 
        id="tableauViz"       
        src='http://public.tableau.com/views/WorldIndicators/GDPpercapita?Region='      
        device="phone" toolbar="bottom" hide-tabs
        >
        </tableau-viz>
        <script type='module'>
            import {TableauEventType} from 'https://uatdataviz.hruk.pri/javascripts/api/tableau.embedding.3.latest.min.js';
            let viz = document.getElementById('tableauViz');
            viz.addEventListener(TableauEventType.FirstInteractive, async (event) => {
                viz.addEventListener(TableauEventType.MarkSelectionChanged, getSelectedMarks);    
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

For example [Tableau Embedding API reference for Event Listeners](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/embedding_api/en-us/docs/embedding_api_event.html)

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. I have to use `https` instead of `http` for viz URL.